# Changing the checkbox size in Android 2.0

Tags: android, android-widget

Ok so I know this has been asked before and there seems to be that all of the answers point to this very old tutorial.

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=17050

My problem with that tutorial is it is over a year old and references the use of files that are not available anymore in the android SDK.

It is also very hard to understand the crux of what I think should be such a simple thing.

Can someone on here please clarify for me.  It would seem that you just set a different drawable as the background and it takes on the size of the drawable.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats right just simply setting the background to your new selector with larger images should do the trick.  You shouldn't need to make a style for your checkboxes like in this tutorial but it could save you some time in the long run.

Comment: It was actually the setButtonDrawable attribute that got me there but this certainly lead me on the right track.  Now if I could only get rid of the extra space next to it: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_MG2-YJ7Y-Xs/TXU-7HxGeaI/AAAAAAAAK4A/BFs7XWKEGQo/s800/Capture.JPG

Comment: @Roloc try messing with the gravity attribute, probably something like android:gravity="left"